# Regarding Scanner class in java which when used in counting provides wrong results

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("input a number");
    Integer a = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println("value of a "+ a);

    for(Integer i = 0 ; i < a; i++){
        a = a + i;
        System.out.println("for loop :"+ a);
    }
    System.out.println("value of a "+a);
    scanner.close();
}
```

When above code is executed, I was expecting the count to go like

```
a = a + i 
a = 5 + 1 
a = 6 + 2 
a = 7 + 3 
....
```

but the answer which is obtained is -2147450875. Please let me know why ?

Comment: > This is the code. When code is executed, i was expecting the count to go like

a = a + i 
a = 5 + 1
a = 6 + 2
a = 7 + 3 ....

but the answer which is obtained is -2147450875. Please let me know why ?

Comment: What is your input?

Comment: For the code , my input given at the scanner class is 5

Comment: Yes, but a is always increasing. You should use a variable sum=0 and add i to sum, not to a.

Comment: Thank you for helping , i was thinking that it was a problem with scanner class.

Comment: P.S. Check how to debug. Debugging tutorials like step into step out(added enough terms to google) will help fixing these issues much faster than Stackoverflow.

Comment: P.S. The reason your loop actually stopped is due to limit of int value, once you crossed I think 2^32 -1, value of `a` went negative causing loop to stop.

Answer (score 1):

You have to store the sum into a different variable else it will become a    non-ending infinite loop.

As Integer class has cyclic property so after `2,147,483,647` the statement         `a = a + i;` makes it a negative number and the for loop check breaks the loop i.e `i(Zero) < a(some negative value)`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("input a number");
    Integer a = scanner.nextInt();
    Integer sum = 0;
    System.out.println("value of a "+ a);

    for(Integer i = 0 ; i < a; i++){
        sum = sum + i;
        System.out.println("for loop :"+ sum);
    }
    System.out.println("value of sum "+sum);
    scanner.close();
}
```